# Alfresco and Solr permission checks

Tags: solr, alfresco

The following code returns a number of results greater than 1000:

```
SearchParameters searchParams = new SearchParameters();
searchParameters.setQuery(query);
searchParameters.setSkipCount(0);
searchParameters.setMaxPermissionChecks(1000);
searchParameters.setPermissionEvaluation(PermissionEvaluationMode.EAGER);
searchParameters.setLimitBy(LimitBy.NUMBER_OF_PERMISSION_EVALUATIONS);
ResultSet results = searchService.query(searchParams);
```

Because I am setting the max permission checks to 1000, I wasn't expecting more than 1000 results.

To get the expected number of results, it is possible to use a different permission evaluation:

```
searchParameters.setPermissionEvaluation(PermissionEvaluationMode.NONE);
```

The problem with this is that Solr will not use its internal permission checks and so performance will be impacted.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to let Solr filter the results based on permissions and at the same time limit the number of permission evaluations?

Comment: How many results do you get back, are you hitting another limit?

Comment: No, I always get all the matching nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read access filtering is done by a simple SOLR filter query, which is extremely efficient and does not really make that much of a difference whether 100 or 100.000 results are matched. As the SOLR filter query handling is an extremely low-level operation that may occur before results are sorted according to relevance, there is also no way for Alfresco to limit the number of "evaluations" without messing with the internals of how SOLR executes queries.
The real performance overhead comes from the fact that in this particular case, an effectively unbounded result page is requested, causing 1) significant transport overhead as the SOLR JSON result has to contain all the matching result's IDs, and 2) the Repository-tier handling of SOLR results aggressively pre-caches the results from the database.

There is generally no sensible use of the `LimitBy.NUMBER_OF_PERMISSION_EVALUATIONS` limitation, especially from an end-user perspective. Limitations should generally always be based on the `LimitBy.FINAL_SIZE` (in combination with `setMaxItems(int)`), as the `maxPermissionChecks` would still be respected **IF** at some point during search execution, Repository-tier permission checking needs to be involved (e.g. processing denied permissions if `security.anyDenyDenies` is enabled and either `security.postProcessDenies` is enabled or SOLR was itself not able / configured to filter denies).

TL;DR: The behaviour is to be expected. The `LimitBy.NUMBER_OF_PERMISSION_EVALUATIONS` is a left-over mode from legacy Lucene that is not applicable to SOLR. It is always recommended to also limit the total number of items to be returned from search via  `setMaxItems(int)`